# javax.mail.messagingexception connection timed out connect

Tags: java, email, outlook, jmail

Below code is the part of the web application. This is responsible to connect with outlook mail server.

```
    ls_user_pass = ldch_sys_users.getItemValue(1, "user_password").toString();      

    Store store = null;     
    String lstr_host = "",lstr_result= "no";
        HttpSession lssessionUserAuth = (HttpSession) ahm_args.get("session");  
        try {               

                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
                Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);                                
                lstr_host = "outlook.office365.com";                    
                store = session.getStore("imaps");
                store.connect(lstr_host, "rajesh___@outlook.com", ls_user_pass);
                if (store.isConnected()) {
                lstr_result = "yes";
                }               
        }catch(AuthenticationFailedException e){

        }
        return lstr_result;
}
```

when I deployed war on server , I am getting this error javax.mail.messagingexception connection timed out connect. 
Already I have opened few port 587,143,25 and on server firewall is off.

But when I work through eclipse on local system, it working fine, without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

It still seems a firewall / network issue.
If you are sending the mail from local, you can check the stream / port/ etc. with WireShark for example, after that you can check the firewall conf again for the server.

You can also try to set the port by hand:
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // "587" should be a string, if not port 25 will be used

For further going, please write down the result of the check.

Comment: Hi Franky,
Sorry for late reply and Thanks for ur suggestion , i have tried ur suggestion but sorry to say it's  not working. Even is hard code properties values also.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply. is the problem is still exists?
If yes, can you please paste the whireshark result with the filter of the port and protocol?
There is ssl cert using possibility also, are you using a certification or just a simple user/pass auth?